# questions about the use of clustering in social science

Tags: r, clustering, social-science

I'm a student in social science. Recently i'm learning clustering, but I really can't understand how can we use clustering in our social science research. For example, I use the 'gender consciousness' and 'political participation' as my features. I used K-means clustering and get to know that there is basically two clusters in the data as the following picture shows:[image: scree plot]

And then I used the scatterplot to visualise these two clusters, as the following picture shows:[image: scatter plot]

After getting these pictures and the clusters distribution, I still have no idea what can I do with thses pictures. The teacher said I can use these unsupervised learning as the preparation for the supervised learning. But in what way can this clusters help me in the following supervised learning(for example, I want to get a linear regression of gender consciousness(IV) and political participation(DV))

If someone can provide me with some relative ideas, I'd be really appreciated!

Comment: Cluster analysis is a very common and also useful method in social science. However, not necessarily in every situation. In your case, you have only two variables and the connection between both is quite obvious. Think for example that you have many variables and thus hard to make a model (supervised). Clustering would help you to group observation and also show, which of the variables are the most crucial for the differences.

Comment: Your cluster plot is misleading because the range of values on gendercon is 4 times larger than c52 so c52 is largely irrelevant to defining your two clusters. If you want variables to be weighted equally, you need to scale them similarly (e.g. standard or z scores). Try plotting the clusters with the aspect ratio set to 1 to see what I mean.

Comment: Are your data quantitative, scale ones? The line of Silhouette values show that there is no clear-cut clusters in the data.